# a controller test with junit 5 generates an error 'that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I use spring boot 2.6.7
when I run the tests, I get an error.

UserDetailsServiceImpl.java

```java
package com.acme.apitutorial.security.services;
...

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
```

UserDetailsImpl.java

```java
package com.acme.apitutorial.security.services;
...
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
...
```

the test class :

TutorialControllerTest.java

```java
package com.acme.apitutorial.controller;
...
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@WebMvcTest(controllers = TutorialController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TutorialControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    TutorialRepository tutorialRepository;

    @Autowired
    TutorialController tutorialController;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {

    }

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        Assertions.assertThat(tutorialController).isNot(null);
    }
```

so when I execute : TutorialControllerTest.java
I get this error :

```
Field userDetailsService in com.acme.apitutorial.security.WebSecurityConfig required a bean of type 'com.acme.apitutorial.security.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.acme.apitutorial.security.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl' in your configuration.
```

I don't understand!

```java
package com.acme.apitutorial.security;
...
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,  // controller -> @Secured("ROLE_VIEWER")
        jsr250Enabled = true,   // controller -> @RoleAllowed(....
        prePostEnabled = true)  // controller -> @PreAuthorize(
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
```

Comment: still not. the same error

Comment: Add.             @Autowired
  UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService in the test class if your controller uses it